# Issues with Chrome extensions displaying and postions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, toolbar, address-bar

I have various extensions that do no usually display in the menu bar, they either display in the address bar, elsewhere or stay hidden.

This morning when I booted up Chrome suddenly these extensions are not in their usual positions but all displaying in the menu bar.

Also if I turn on any other of my extensions they do not appear, they are hidden by default (they weren't set on hidden before) and I have to drag the address bar to the left so they appear in the menu bar.

This doesn't seem to be a local issue, as I have spoke with 4 other people who all are seeing the same issue.

What's happening here, is this due to a Chrome update?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide extensions from chrome without pushing to chrome bar](http://superuser.com/questions/1048044/hide-extensions-from-chrome-without-pushing-to-chrome-bar)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same, along with a popup saying Chrome has updated extensions.  It looks like this is the new layout.

You can right click and click hide and it will put them under the menu at the right.